# Cannot get Tomcat 10 to run on a Mac with Java 17

Tags: java-17, macos-ventura, tomcat10

I just installed jdk-17.jdk on my Mac running Ventura 13.5, to support my install of apache-tomcat-10.1.12.

I used the DMG installer for Java 17, and I received no errors.

When I attempt to start up Tomcat using: startup.sh, I receive the following error:

```
**The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE**
```

I can see the DMG installed installed Java into:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk

```
    And my JAVA_HOME variable is set in my .tcshrc
    setenv JAVA_HOME /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk

    And I also set these two Tomcat Environment Variables: 
    setenv CATALINA_HOME /Users/../Desktop/apache-tomcat-10.1.12 
    setenv CATALINA_BASE /Users/../Desktop/apache-tomcat-10.1.12
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to configure the correct path for **JAVA_HOME** in your environment variable.

> In macOS, the installed jdk path looks like this:
>
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home

**JAVA_HOME=**/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home